# How to import/create multiple events from .csv?

Tags: civievent, api

how do one import/create multiple events from an existing .csv file?

I checked the "API csv Import"-Extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui). But this only updates existing events.

1. Does anybody know a different method?

or

2. I thought of creating multiple "empty" events with only an event-id and then updating it through the api-csv-import-ui. Can somebody give me a hint how to do that? (I am not super experienced with the api). Or even providing me with a code snippet, for create multiple events with event-ids from x-y.

Thanks in advance.
Stefan

---

I am using

- drupal7
- CiviCRM 5.30.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use the API CSV extension to import new events. Here is a good guide to do so: https://wapix.co/importing-events-to-civicrm/.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. Important: "To import a set of new data, **omit** the Event ID field"